# How can I make my flexbox container to vertically autoexapnd with the content?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

As you can see in the screenshot attached, the content is overflowing. I don't want to use overflow because I don't want to scroll "inside" the div .results container, I want it to expand with the content as necessary. I've been Googling a lot, but the solutions I've tried, for example min-height, destroys the layout, for example by pushing upwards the upper part until it is not longer visible nor accessible.

[image: Screenshot]

```css
* {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: "Assistant";
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #333333;
}

.main-main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(154,160,185,.5), 0 15px 40px rgba(166,173,201,.2);
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.top-section {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 20%;
    display: flex;
    background-color: #caf0f8;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
}
.instructions {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;

}

.my-button {
  height: 20%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ade8f4;
}

.results {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 80%;
  padding: 60px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: #90e0ef;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

button {
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 60px;
    border: 0px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #03045e;
}

#my-input {
    height: 60px;
    width: 500px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    border: 0px;
}

::placeholder {
    color: lightblue;
}

.my-box {
    background-color: #ffff3f;
    font-size: 40px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
    <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-main">
        <div class="main-container">
            <div class="top-section">
                <div class="instructions"><input type="text" id="my-input" placeholder="Enter string..."></div>
                <div class="instructions"><button type="button" id="my-button">Arrayify!</button></div>
            </div>
            <div class="results" id="my-results"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `height` from all surrounding containers to let them stretch vertically to fit their contents.

Comment: Still not working :\

Comment: @idankor There's another container with a `height`; edited my answer. If it stil doesn't work, please update the code in your question to show the actual problem (right now it has an empty container).